# Через Интернет или по Интернету

Tags: выбор-слова, лексикон

Как правильно сказать: "Через Интернет" или "по Интернету", или оба варианта правильные?

Comment: В каком контексте?

Comment: Например "я забронировал номер в гостинице..."

Comment: Интересно, ваша фамилия действительно Путин?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оба варианта правильные. Забронировать гостиницу, заказать что-то - через Интернет/по Интернету. А вот если, например, "узнать что-то", то правильней будет "из Интернета" или "в Интернете"